# How to find the max and min value of the pixels in an image

Tags: compositing-nodes

How do find the max and min value of the pixels in an image? Assume there is a ready-baked render image and I want to ascertain the max and min  RGB value across all pixels of the render.

Comment: In the image editor side panel there's a tab called "Scopes".  One of the scopes is the histogram, but that only gets you the overview.  You can hand sample individual pixels using the eyedropper from the toolbar to get exact values, but as far as I know, there is no built-in way to get the min/max.  It wouldn't be hard to write a python script; probably using numpy but this sounds like a better task for image processing software.

Comment: Yea, but I want to obtain precise values for utilizing them in the Compositing purpose

Comment: Is python scripting an option ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yea, of course!

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124265/86891

Comment: Thank you, I should dig in

Comment: @Gorgious Okay, it for sure does sense but I am a little bit confused about how to do the same not for an imported image but for data that are going from an output of a node in Compositing. Assume we wanna get the max and min values from the V (value) output of the "Separate HSVA" node is it possible?